# LinqToCSV and decimal globalization

Tags: c#, linq, csv, decimal-point, linqtocsv

I'm trying to read a csv file using LingToCSV, containing decimal values with a comma a seperator instead of a point.

This is one row of input:

```
"DataField1","DataField2"
"Test", "0,34"
```

And I use this class to read it:

```
public class Record
{
   [CsvColumn(Name = "DataField1", FieldIndex=  1)]
   string DataField1 {get;set;}

   [CsvColumn(Name = "DataField2", FieldIndex=  2, OutputFormat="C", NumberStyle=NumberStyles.Currency)]
   decimal DataField2 {get;set;}
}
```

However, this doesn't work and generates this exception:

> {"Value \"DataField2\" in line 9 has the wrong format for field or
>   property \"DataFoe;d2\" in type \"Record\"."}

Obviously it's expecting a point, but how can I make it work using the commas.

Comment: Can we propose a solution without LinqToCsv?

Comment: Well, I appreciate you're helping me problem solving without using a specific technique. But we need to write a lot of CSV parsers (to link our application to a lot of different providers). And I was experimenting with LinqToCSV because it is so easy to use and quick to write, and I was wondering if it was possible using LinqToCSV

Comment: Is "0,34" an appropriate value for a currency type?  I'd try some other values there.  Is that a typo?  Or, should it be "0.34".

Comment: It is in the netherlands, so that's kinda my question.

Comment: You probably have to set some sort of currency culture format.

Comment: What bugs me, is that the error message says "in Line 9". Is the format of the values before Line 9 and after Line 9 different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Believe you need to set the FileCultureName in the CsvFileDescription...

```
CsvFileDescription fileDesc = new CsvFileDescription
        {

            FirstLineHasColumnNames = true
            FileCultureName = "nl" 
        };
```

Comment: or pass in a `FileCultureInfo` directly

Comment: The eternal benefit of a second set of eyes.